# how to keep 24hours00minut in a timestamp value in oracle and java

Tags: java, time, timestamp

In first step we generate date in timestamp format ;
And in second step (other feature of our application) we need to extract the date only; and it's important to keep the day before and not day after midnight.

Thanks for your support.

RL

Answer (score 1):

In **Java-8**, there is partial support for 24:00-time (midnight at end of day) ONLY on parsing level, and then only for `LocalTime`.

**Automatical transfer of 24:00 to next day:**

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
TemporalAccessor parsed = dtf.parse("2016-11-14 24:00");
Period extraDays = parsed.query(DateTimeFormatter.parsedExcessDays());
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.from(parsed);
System.out.println(ldt);
System.out.println(extraDays);
```

Output:

> 2016-11-15T00:00
>
> P0D (24:00 has been lost!!!)

For `LocalDateTime`, there does not seem to exist any way to find out that the original parsed time was "24:00". However, if you work with the type `LocalTime` then you can query the original time this similar way:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
TemporalAccessor parsed2 = dtf2.parse("24:00");
Period extraDays2 = parsed2.query(DateTimeFormatter.parsedExcessDays());
System.out.println(extraDays2); // P1D
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.from(parsed2);
System.out.println(lt); // 00:00
```

**You could set up two formatters, one for the date part only and one for the time part as given in last example.** However, what you can NEVER do is storing the time 24:00 as instance of `LocalTime`. Instead, you must work with the formatter method [parsedExcessDays()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parsedExcessDays--) So you find that the overall support is very limited. The best solution I found is this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd ");
DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

String input = "2016-11-14 24:00";
ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.from(dtf1.parse(input, pp));
TemporalAccessor timePart = dtf2.parse(input, pp);
Period extraDays = timePart.query(DateTimeFormatter.parsedExcessDays());
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.from(timePart);

System.out.println(ld); // 2016-11-14
System.out.println(lt); // 00:00
System.out.println(extraDays); // P1D
```

---

Maybe you can consider my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) as alternative format and parse engine. A major difference here is: **The Time4J-type `PlainTime` can store the value "24:00".**

But like Java-8, the type `PlainTimestamp` (as pendant to `LocalDateTime`) also does an automatic transfer of excess days to date part. Main reason is to avoid difficulties in sorting and implementation of the natural order. Consider for example the timestamps 2016-11-14 24:00 and 2016-11-15 00:00. Both values would be temporally equal (simultaneous) but are not equal (regarding the whole state), so the natural order would be inconsistent with `equals()`. Therefore a `PlainTimestamp` does not store 24:00 but automatically resolves it to next day.

But you can use this solution keeping date and time separately:

```
ChronoFormatter<PlainDate> dateF =
    ChronoFormatter.ofDatePattern("yyyy-MM-dd ", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT).with(
        Attributes.TRAILING_CHARACTERS,
        true
    );
ChronoFormatter<PlainTime> timeF =
    ChronoFormatter.ofTimePattern("HH:mm", PatternType.CLDR_24, Locale.ROOT);

String input = "2016-11-14 24:00";
ParseLog plog = new ParseLog();

PlainDate date = dateF.parse(input, plog);
PlainTime time = timeF.parse(input, plog);
System.out.println(date); // 2016-11-14
System.out.println(time); // T24
```

Of course, the transformation to Java-8-types is in general possible but keep in mind that the conversion of `PlainTime` to `LocalTime` via the method `toTemporalAccessor()` will map the time value 24:00 to 00:00 (lossy conversion).